# Order statistics tree using __gnu_pbds for multiset

Tags: c++, stl, gnu

I am trying to implement an order statistics tree with using __gnu__pbds. I followed this code [TREE_ORDER_STATISTICS](https://opensource.apple.com/source/llvmgcc42/llvmgcc42-2336.9/libstdc++-v3/testsuite/ext/pb_ds/example/tree_order_statistics.cc.auto.html)

But, I need this on a multiset. I was suggested to use a pair to implement this feature [CODEFORCES COMMENT](http://codeforces.com/blog/entry/11080)

```
//Main idea is to keep pairs like {elem, id}.

typedef tree<
    pair<int, int>,
    null_type,
    less<pair<int, int>>,
    rb_tree_tag,
    tree_order_statistics_node_update> ordered_set;

int t = 0;

ordered_set me;
...
me.insert({x, t++});
me.erase(me.lower_bound({x, 0}));
cout << me.order_of_key({x, 0}) << "\n";
```

But, how would I use `find_by_order(k)` for this case?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to change the comparison function from `less` to `less_equal` asn in the following:

```
typedef tree<
    int,
    null_type,
    less_equal<int>,
    rb_tree_tag,
    tree_order_statistics_node_update> ordered_set;
```

Comment: The containers aren't designed for this and it's probably undefined behavior. See https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/ext/pb_ds/motivation.html#assoc_mapping_semantics.

Comment: A drawback of using less_equal instead of less is that lower_bound works as upper_bound

Answer (score 9):

**A drawback of using less_equal instead of less is that lower_bound works as upper_bound**

One way to do is to store pair

```
typedef tree<
pair<int, int>,
null_type,
less<pair<int, int>>,
rb_tree_tag,
tree_order_statistics_node_update> ordered_set;

int t = 0;

ordered_set me;
...
me.insert({x, t++});
me.erase(me.lower_bound({x, 0}));
cout << me.order_of_key({x, 0}) << "\n";
```

source: adamant https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/11080

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead:

```
s.erase(s.find_by_order(v[a]));
```